# How to set up a wifi hotspot connection in elementary os

Tags: release-juno, wifi, internet

on elementary os 5.0 juuno how i do set the hotspot function that may allo to surf the web using my laptop and my sansung smartphone?

I am supposed to activate the hotspot function in settings, and the one in my smartphone and am i ready to go or have to do something more?

[image: hotspot function in elementary os]

Answer (score 0):

Actually, [there is an article on fosslinux.com about it](https://www.fosslinux.com/603/how-to-create-wi-fi-hotspot-in-elementary-os.htm) but it needs a manual adjustment on the connection profile file, located in:

```
/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Personal_Wi-Fi_Hotspot
```

replacing mode=infrastructure and change it to mode=ap

Anyone has tryed and works?

Answer (score 0):

It was even more simplier; just activate the wifi on elementary os, and then the router option on your smartphone, and follow the isctruction on its screen, pick the SSID that you cell tells you and the relative password and then click on the SSID showd by elementary os, supply the password and you're done.

I guess it maight be a little different becaus of the smartphone you own, i have a Samsung Galaxy A8 and it worked flawlessy.